# Access network or Internet without the INTERNET permission on Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I was wondering, is it possible to access what the INTERNET permissions grants, without actually requesting that permission?

Environment: rooted Android phone from API 15 (Android 4.0.3) to the newest one at the time of the answer and app as system app with privileged permissions. No signature permissions, but supposed I have them too. Just ANY way.

I'm asking this not to do some stupid stuff (hopefully no one that reads this will do, if there are any positive answers). Asking because I'm making an assistant app which is supposed to control the entire phone if needed, and requests many permissions. If the INTERNET one is not one of them, if I publish it on some store, people could be relaxed about privacy, since I can't send anything out - or can I still...?

If I can, I'll just let them know there's no way to be sure I won't steal their privacy except by trust (I guess? Or there's some other way I didn't think of?). If there's no way, well, done. Easy. Just don't include it and it's fine about privacy (would have to think about ads, but that's something else - reduced and full version or something).

Comment: You gonna rely on trust at some point if you are that skeptical. Is the API really doing what it is supposed to do and nothing more? Does the OS really run your APP as-is? Does the OS secretly send out your data? (Yes the OS could be open source, but in most cases you are using some prebuilt and not really verifying it). Does the hardware really is what it is specified? There are so many level you can doubt and just really rely on trust (or trust the community for verifying). Even you get an answer for this question, you can still ask "is this answer trustable?".

Comment: Well, it's not for me. I try to trust on stuff. That's why I install anything that could do what I need on my phone. On computer too. But there I have an antivirus to help with detection aside from InfiniteLifeInstaller000423313.exe 3 kB obvious stupid name/size XD. It's for whoever uses the app. People might not like it requesting many permissions, like one which is "GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"... So this way I could kind of relax them - INTERNET is not a runtime permission. In any case, answers usually are fundamented by something. I'd go and check it out too to be informed about the subject.